# Java code to create bigquery table using json schema

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to create a bigquery table using java. I first want to create table using json schema and then later on will write data flow program to populate it. Can anyone give me a sample code to create the table ?

Comment: -1 You seem to be asking for a tutorial with your request for sample code. SO isn't a place for sample code tutorials; can you rephrase your question so that it is more specific about what you have attempted so far and hones in on the issues you have encountered? You will be much more likely to get help if you post your code and allow people to help you get that to work.

Comment: You can find everything you need on the Github examples page. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/bigquery

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. I have a JSON schema file and don't want to duplicate the schema again in Java like so [1]. The Java library doesn't seem to support importing a JSON schema file with something like `Schema.of("path/to/JSON")`.

[1]: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creating_an_empty_table_with_a_schema_definition

Comment: Functionality in my comment above is on Google's backlog. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/2553

Answer (score 2):

These docs have example code for setting up a BQ table in java. Hope this helps

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#bigquery-create-table-java